# AMP story close button

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-stories

I would like to add a close button to my AMP stories. I don't want to use amp-story-play if it's possible. I checked the source code and I found a close button, but it's hidden.

```
...
<button class="i-amphtml-story-close-control i-amphtml-story-ui-hide-button i-amphtml-story-button" aria-label="Close"></button>
...
```

When I removed the `i-amphtml-story-ui-hide-button` class then [I can see the X on the story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0paJ.png)

So my plan to make this permanent somehow. What I tried:

- create a js event to modify the class when the page is loaded, it's returning null so I can't modify the class in time
- I modified the official source code, but I have no idea how to generate the `amp-story-system-layer.js` ... I tried with `amp build`, `amp release`, run the circle ci/cd commands, but it won't generate the js file that I need

Does anyone have an idea how to add a close button to the story?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps !!

```
<amp-story standalone ...> 
 ...content
 <amp-story-exit layout="nodisplay">
  <div exit-label>
    <span className="exit-text">Close story</span>
    <span className="exit-icon">X</span>
  </div>
 </amp-story-exit>
</amp-story>
```